# Conda environment messes up Slurm+OpenMPI+PMIx

Tags: python, anaconda, slurm, openmpi, pmix

I used `mambaforge` to create a virtual environment on a HPC cluster with Slurm. When I activate that environment and run a python script:

```
source ~/.bashrc
conda activate myEnv

srun python some_python_code.py
```

I get

```
[sh03-05n17.int:28613] OPAL ERROR: Unreachable in file pmix3x_client.c at line 112
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
The application appears to have been direct launched using "srun",
but OMPI was not built with SLURM's PMI support and therefore cannot
execute. There are several options for building PMI support under
SLURM, depending upon the SLURM version you are using:

  version 16.05 or later: you can use SLURM's PMIx support. This
  requires that you configure and build SLURM --with-pmix.

  Versions earlier than 16.05: you must use either SLURM's PMI-1 or
  PMI-2 support. SLURM builds PMI-1 by default, or you can manually
  install PMI-2. You must then build Open MPI using --with-pmi pointing
  to the SLURM PMI library location.

Please configure as appropriate and try again.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[sh03-05n17.int:28613] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed completed successfully, but am not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
srun: error: sh03-05n17: task 1: Exited with exit code 1
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=326149.0
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 326149.0 ON sh03-05n06 CANCELLED AT 2022-11-09T20:02:55 ***
srun: error: sh03-05n23: task 2: Terminated
srun: error: sh03-14n18: task 4: Terminated
srun: error: sh03-14n17: task 3: Terminated
srun: error: sh03-05n06: task 0: Terminated
srun: Force Terminated StepId=326149.0
```

The core piece of this error message apparently is within the dashed lines.

I tried to run a different script (but using MPI) without activating this virtual environment, and Slurm+openMPI+PMIx are working together happily. Since there is only one Slurm on this HPC system, and it seems like it is configured properly to work with openMPI+PMIx, then I don't really want to mess with Slurm (frankly I also don't know how can I get rid of Slurm on the HPC system and re-build it myself). Please correct me if this is indeed something I will have to do.

I think the issue is more likely that some of these auxiliary packages (i.e. openMPI, PMIx) are not properly installed/configured in the virtual environment. I checked that the virtual environment has `openMPI/4.1.4`. I tried to load the system's original `openMPI/4.1.2` into the virtual environment and the problem persists.

If I do `srun --mpi=list` in the batch job script, I see

```
MPI plugin types are...
    cray_shasta
    pmix
    pmi2
    none
specific pmix plugin versions available: pmix_v3
```

which appears to be normal.

If I do `srun --mpi=pmix python some_python_code.py`, I get a different error message;

```
[sh03-05n23.int:02905] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n23.int:02905] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n23.int:02905] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n03.int:27534] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n03.int:27534] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n03.int:27534] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n03.int:27534] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n23.int:02905] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-04n56.int:27675] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-04n56.int:27675] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n17.int:26936] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n17.int:26936] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n17.int:26936] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n17.int:26936] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-04n56.int:27675] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-04n56.int:27675] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n06.int:21973] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n06.int:21973] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
[sh03-05n06.int:21973] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file base/bfrop_base_unpack.c at line 692
[sh03-05n06.int:21973] PMIX ERROR: BAD-PARAM in file dstore_base.c at line 2225
distributed.http.proxy - INFO - To route to workers diagnostics web server please install jupyter-server-proxy: python -m pip install jupyter-server-proxy
distributed.scheduler - INFO - Clear task state
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   Scheduler at:    tcp://10.51.4.56:35403
distributed.scheduler - INFO -   dashboard at:           10.51.4.56:8787
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 32 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 325679 ON sh03-04n56 CANCELLED AT 2022-11-09T19:51:11 ***
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 325679.0 ON sh03-04n56 CANCELLED AT 2022-11-09T19:51:11 ***
```

and in this case the job will become stuck and will have to be manually cancelled or until it times out.

I want to confirm if my understanding that Slurm should not be touched is correct? And if so/not so what should I do to fix this problem? At the end this might be a question of how to set the various configuration values for openMPI when it is installed by Anaconda. [This page](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/openmpi) certainly has no info on that at all.

Thank you!